# React Navigation navigate to specific tab

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

[The example on React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#jumpto) shows how you can jump to a tab, but it shows it in the case you are in the navigator the tabs are part of.
But how do you navigate to a specific tab from a screen which is part of a different navigator?

I have:

```
function MealsNavigator() {
  const MealsStack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <MealsStack.Navigator>
      <MealsStack.Screen
        name="Meals"
        component={MealsScreenTabs}
      />
    </MealsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function MealsScreenTabs() {
  const MealsTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
  return (
    <MealsTabs.Navigator>
      <MealsTabs.Screen name="Upcoming" component={MealsUpcomingScreen} />
      <MealsTabs.Screen name="Past" component={MealsPastScreen} />
    </MealsTabs.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I want to be able to navigate to Meals > Past with a button click from my Profile screen inside the Account navigator. How?

Comment: Can you write here the nesting of your screens?
where is the Account navigator?

Comment: The tabs are in the Meals navigator, why is it important to look at the Account navigator?

Answer (score 6):

Got some help from the community on Discord. Here' how you do it:

```
navigation.navigate('Meals', {
  screen: 'Meals',
  params: {screen: 'Past'},
})
```

And to see it in action, [have a look at a snack I created](https://snack.expo.io/@kickbk/react-navigation-jumpto-specific-tab)

Answer (score 5):

in react navigation v5

`navigation.navigate('Meals', {screen: 'Past'});`

Comment: This simply navigates to the Meals navigator and shows the last selected tab. So if I last selected 'Upcoming' and do `navigate('Meals', {screen: 'Past'});`, it will navigate to Meals and show 'Upcoming'. Not 'Past'